# Find directory with space in name with powershell

Tags: powershell

Directions: The password for Century5 is the name of the file within a directory on the desktop that has spaces in its name.

Working on underthewire game using powershell and need to find a directory on the desktop that contains spaces in its name. So far I've tried the following but it just seems to give the same output:

```
[century.underthewire.tech]: PS C:\Users\century4\Desktop> get-childitem * *


    Directory: C:\Users\century4\Desktop


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                           
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                           
d-----         6/8/2017   4:16 PM                1                                                                           199                                                                
d-----         6/8/2017   4:17 PM                200                                                                     299                                                                    
d-----         6/8/2017   4:17 PM                300                                                                      399                                                                   
d-----         6/8/2017   4:17 PM                400                                                                   499                                                                      
d-----         6/8/2017   4:19 PM                500                                                                                                                         501                



[century.underthewire.tech]: PS C:\Users\century4\Desktop> get-childitem | where-object {$_ -match ' '}


    Directory: C:\Users\century4\Desktop


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                           
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                           
d-----         6/8/2017   4:16 PM                1                                                                           199                                                                
d-----         6/8/2017   4:17 PM                200                                                                     299                                                                    
d-----         6/8/2017   4:17 PM                300                                                                      399                                                                   
d-----         6/8/2017   4:17 PM                400                                                                   499                                                                      
d-----         6/8/2017   4:19 PM                500                                                                                                                         501
```

It seems like they all have spaces. I could probably just check in each directory for the file containing the password, but I'd like to learn to filter.

Comment: If all the names are containing spaces, this is the output you will receive. Can you please provide the correct names of the files ? For example: "     199", "299", etc. And also, please try `where-object {$_.Name -match ' '}`

Comment: This command returned no output at all, but no errors either.

Comment: The only directory that had anything in it is the following: `500                                                                                                                         501`

Seems obvious when you see that 501 is further to the right than the others, but I'm wondering how you can automate this search.

Comment: Sorry. My code was bad `Get-ChildItem -directory|foreach-object{"'$($_.name)'"}`. That would help outline leading and trailing whitespace. From the looks of it you have multiple matches. Your code is working correctly. What are you expecting?

Comment: From the wording in the directions, I'd assume a correct search to include a directory with "spaces" to reveal only one solution. The difference between 'get-childitem' and appending any other switches or attempts to refine the search did not change the results. The shell is rather buggy though and has a pretty bad help guide.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell RegEx `\s` represents a white-space. Also use the `-Directory` paramter to get directories only, and filter for the `BaseName` property, to not match for the full path.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory | Where-Object {$_.Name -match '\s'}
```

Comment: Basename is a proxy property that removes extensions. Directories do not have those so it is redundant. `Name` is sufficient. From the look of the question this might give the op the same results anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I was thinking the default property might be the FullName. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: It did give the same results:

Comment: also, simply using the below command gives the exact same results:

    `Get-childitem`

Comment: I just recognized that the directories in your output indeed contain (many) white-spaces, hence everything works as I'd expect. What's your expected output?